# Disable g++ "note candidates are.." compiler message

Tags: c++, g++

Many times when I compile something with a typo or some other typing mismatch, I get the standard "error: no match for 'functionname' in ..." error. This is great. Then, especially in the case of overloaded functions and operators, g++ goes on and list like 10 pages of candidates which are just hideous and massive template definitions.

The error message is great, but is there any way to disable it from suggesting other functions variants?

Comment: Wait, you want the error message to have *less* information?

Comment: The function definitions it suggests are hidden behind 10 layers of templating (especially with boost) and make it much harder to find where the compiler actually identifies the line with the error. I want it to tell me where the error was and what was wrong, but I don't really need it to suggest how to fix it.

Comment: pipe it through grep, only match on lines that have 'error:' in them? FWIW my development environment has 'jump to the line with the error' as a feature, which as an added bonus leaves the top of the list of candidates showing on screen.

Comment: use clang. It has much nicer error messages.

Comment: @Simon, clang++ won't help here, it offers `-fshow-candidates=<value>` but the argument can only be `best` or `all` not e.g. `none`

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Unhelpful information can be less helpful than no information, especially when you need to scroll through pages of repetitive text just to try to figure out what the actual error is.

Comment: If you want to see a particularly pernicious instance of this, try `boost::variant<bool, int> value; std::ifstream input("filename.txt"); input >> value;`  Produces about 50k of output in GCC 5.3.1.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no compilation flag in GCC to disable the suggested candidates in case of ambiguous function calls.

Your only hope is perhaps to patch the GCC source code.

Digging in it (version: *4.7.1*), I've found what appear to be the relevant function in `gcc/cp/pt.c`:

```
void
print_candidates(tree fns)
{
  const char *str = NULL;
  print_candidates_1 (fns, false, &str);
  gcc_assert (str == NULL);
}
```

As an educated guess, I think that you only need to comment out the function body.

Comment: +1 for the double LOL. i first thought it was only a tounge-in-cheek answers. then i realized that with gcc it's *common* to build the compiler from source, and that at one time i knew that! the only thing that baffles me now is the apparent modern C/C++ function head. as i recall (but i may be wrong) it used to be old K&R C syntax everywhere?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It was the first time I looked at the GCC code base  and it is probably _too clean_ for a project of this size. As for the K&R C syntax, I am 10 years too young to even know what it is :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf yes! The code evolved a lot, some C++ features are even allowed since may 2010. And I agree that the code base is actually surprisingly clear!

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about patching actually, and then switching between patched and unpatched depending on whether I want all the mess.

Comment: Hmmm why not instead just add your own option in patched version? Shouldn't be that hard, and you will avoid constant switching compilers.

Comment: @j_kubik It is doable, but the patch will be not 5 lines long anymore

Comment: True. perhaps something to share with the community then? If I have a moment I might even look into it.

Comment: @Gigi It seems that it's only few lines after all. It only requires adjustments to gcc/c-family/c.opt and `print_candidates` function. Currently I  cannot confirm that it works because even original gcc fails to compile on my machine, and I don't have time to resolve it.

Comment: you probably also want to patch call.c for non-template cases, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11437155/981959) for a patch

Answer (score 16):

Does `-Wfatal-errors` do what you want?

It stops **all** errors after the first one, which is not the same as simply suppressing the candidate function notes, but it reduces the output significantly:

```
$ cat a.cc
void f() { }
void f(int) { }
void f(char) { }

int main()
{
  f((void*)0);
}
$ g++ a.cc
a.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cc:7: error: call of overloaded ‘f(void*)’ is ambiguous
a.cc:2: note: candidates are: void f(int) <near match>
a.cc:3: note:                 void f(char) <near match>
$ g++ a.cc -Wfatal-errors
a.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cc:7: error: call of overloaded ‘f(void*)’ is ambiguous
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Or, if you wanted to patch GCC, this adds a `-fno-candidate-functions` switch:

```
--- gcc/c-family/c.opt.orig 2012-07-11 16:37:29.373417154 +0000
+++ gcc/c-family/c.opt      2012-07-11 17:09:47.340418384 +0000
@@ -752,6 +752,10 @@
 fbuiltin-
 C ObjC C++ ObjC++ Joined

+fcandidate-functions
+C++ ObjC++ Var(flag_candidates) Init(1)
+-fno-candidate-functions Do not print candidate functions when overload resolution fails
+
 fcheck-new
 C++ ObjC++ Var(flag_check_new)
 Check the return value of new
--- gcc/cp/call.c.orig      2012-07-11 17:08:34.186424089 +0000
+++ gcc/cp/call.c   2012-07-11 17:09:51.843444951 +0000
@@ -3317,6 +3317,9 @@
   for (n_candidates = 0, cand1 = candidates; cand1; cand1 = cand1->next)
     n_candidates++;

+  if (!flag_candidates)
+    return;
+
   inform_n (loc, n_candidates, "candidate is:", "candidates are:");
   for (; candidates; candidates = candidates->next)
     print_z_candidate (loc, NULL, candidates);
--- gcc/cp/pt.c.orig        2012-07-11 16:37:35.658636650 +0000
+++ gcc/cp/pt.c     2012-07-11 17:10:20.910435942 +0000
@@ -1751,9 +1751,12 @@
 void
 print_candidates (tree fns)
 {
-  const char *str = NULL;
-  print_candidates_1 (fns, false, &str);
-  gcc_assert (str == NULL);
+  if (flag_candidates)
+    {
+      const char *str = NULL;
+      print_candidates_1 (fns, false, &str);
+      gcc_assert (str == NULL);
+    }
 }

 /* Returns the template (one of the functions given by TEMPLATE_ID)
```

Comment: Doesnt answer the question obviously but I would guess this works for what many people are looking for in this question

Answer (score 14):

My answer is not as cool as a patch. If you want a less verbose error message, this script will remove the ugly code, and just leave the line number for the candidates.

```
g++ test.cc 2>&1 | sed 's/^\([^ ]*:[0-9]*: note\):.*/\1/'
```

So, it can be used in a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
GXX=/usr/bin/g++
ARGS=()
i=0
show_notes=yes
for arg in "$@" ; do
    if [ "$arg" = "-fterse-notes" ] ; then
        show_notes=no
    elif [ "$arg" = "-fno-terse-notes" ] ; then
        show_notes=yes
    else
        ARGS[$i]="$arg"
        i=$[i+1]
    fi
done
if [ $show_notes = yes ] ; then
    exec ${GXX} "${ARGS[@]}"
else
    exec ${GXX} "${ARGS[@]}" 2>&1 | sed 's/^\([^ ]*:[0-9]*: note\):.*/\1/'
fi
```

If the name of this script is `g++` and in your path, it should work as if you have added a command line option called `-fterse-notes`.

Comment: Surely you only want to increment $i inside the first 'else'?

Comment: @cdyson37 Fixed, thanks!